# Geolocation is not working (firefox 61)

Tags: node.js, linux, firefox, geolocation, manjaro

Here's my code for getting the geolocation. It's working on Windows but not on my laptop on which I run Manjaro KDE 17.1.1.

Every time I try to check my location I get an alert that the browser is unable to fetch location even thought I've allowed it when it prompted me.

[It is deployed to Heroku here.](https://radiant-gorge-47143.herokuapp.com/)

```
var locationButton = $('#send-location');
locationButton.on('click', function() {
  if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    return alert('Geolocation not supported by your browser');
  }

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(position) {
      console.log(position);
    },
    function() {
      alert('Unable to fetch location');
    }
  );
});
```